# Cannot find i in the for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I can't seem to get the last "i" in this code to fully function, it wont respond to the initial "i", just tells me that it "cannot find symbol". What am I doing wrong?

```
    public void fillCB (JComboBox cb){

    String sqlQueryCB = "select namn from ANSTALLD order by namn";

    try {
    ArrayList<String> listaAnstalld = idb.fetchColumn(sqlQueryCB);

    for(int i = 0; i < listaAnstalld.size(); i++); {
            cb.addItem(listaAnstalld.get(i));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon after your `for` statement.

Answer (score 3):

you have a semicolon at the end of your for loop, before the opening brace.

```
for(int i = 0; i < listaAnstalld.size(); i++); {
```

That semicolon closes the `for` loop. should remove it.

because of this, the contents of your block will not be in the scope of the `for` loop(and therefore not in the same scope that `i` is in).